# Missing Windows 8 entry in Grub 2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. I used boot-repair but Windows entry is not showing up.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10418271/

Should I setup UEFI or legacy support in BIOS setting?

Comment: Try executing `update-grub` from within your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Install Grub Customizer in Ubuntu.

Installation procedure is given [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/).

After you have installed the tool open it from the dash. The tool will scan for other OS installed in the system and will list it under the List configuration tab. You should see your Windows 8 entry there.

Next go to General settings tab. Select the default OS of your choice in default entry.
Under visibility check "show menu", check "look for other operating systems" and finally set the "Boot default entry after" time.

Now Save the configuration and let the tool finish its job. After that reboot your system and check Windows 8 entry has returned or not.